# How can i display data from selected row in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn php with html and I decided to create a project.
Right now, I'm stuck at this point where I want to display data on a textarea.
I created a database named 'company' with the table 'login' and the columns 'id','password' and 'username'.

When I select an option in the select option menu, the data from the column 'id','password' and 'username' is displayed in a table. What I want to achieve is when I click on a row, that the data from the column "problem" is displayed on the textarea which describes the situation with explanation.

I don't know how to write this but the syntax should be something like: `Select 'problem' from login WHERE id='selected row id'` I created on my php a select case witch works fine. The only problem that I have is I don't know how to select the id when I click on a specific row to display the data on the textarea.

Here's my code so far:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Formulaire</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="formulaire.css"/>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="select1.js"></script>-->



<!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>-->

<style>
table tr:not(:first-child){
cursor: pointer;transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
table tr:not(:first-child):hover{background-color: #ddd;}
</style>



  
</head>

<body>

<div id="form">

<form action="#" method="post">

<label>Veuillez choisir une option :</label>
<select id="choix" name="choixtest">
  <option value="tous">tous</option>
  <option value="id">id</option>
  <option value="username">username</option>
  <option value="password">password</option>
 </select>
 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />

 <table id="table">
  
 <?php
  
 /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
 server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "company");
 
 // Check connection
 if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 
 // Attempt select query execution
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM login";


 if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>id</th>";
                echo "<th>username</th>";
                echo "<th>password</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $selected_val = $_POST['choixtest'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable

     
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    
    switch($_POST['choixtest']){
     
    case 'tous':
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    break; 
     
    case 'id':
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[$selected_val] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>"  . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    break;
        
    case 'username':
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row[$selected_val] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>"  . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
     break;
    
    case 'password':
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td>"  . $row[$selected_val] .  "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";   
    break;
    
    default:
     // Something went wrong or form has been tampered.
    }
     
                
        }
   

        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
 } else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
 }
 
 // Close connection
 mysqli_close($link);
 ?>
</table>
 
   
<textarea id="erreur" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>

</form>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a table with `<table id="myTable">`to get the first column value into a textbox which is defined as

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Customer Name" id="cus_name">
```

You can add the following js code.

```
<script>
var table = document.getElementById('myTable');        
    for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        table.rows[i].onclick = function()
        {
            document.getElementById("cus_name").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
        };
    }                                                                         
</script>
```

Here the `cus_name` is the id of the text field while in the `this.cells[0]`, the value `0` represents the first column. You can change it accordingly and also can add more columns with the code `document.getElementById("cus_name").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;` by only changing the cell value and the textbox id.

Answer (score 0):

Every row in your html table must correspond to an id in the login table.
you have to place somewhere in the row the id corresponding to that row. You can achieve this in many ways.
one way to do it is using a data-something attribute to put the id, for instance

```
<tr data-id="<?php echo $current_row['id']; ?>">  
    <td>column1</td>
    <td>column2</td>
    <td>etcetera</td>
</tr>
```

Once you have the data-id atttribute set you can access it via Javascript everytime a user clicks on the row. For this you need to capture the click event on the row. I'll show you an example using jQuery:

```
$('.myTable tr').click(function(){
    let id = $('this').data('id');
    console.log('id of selected row: ' + id);
});
```

Now the 'id' variable contains the id of the row the user selected (check console output to make sure the id is the one you expect). The next step would be to use that id to make a request to the server, via Ajax or via regular http request. If this works successfully i suggest you to research, or make another post to find out how to reload the page with the content with the data you want. Since the more specific a question is the higher is the chance that it will be answered